# Can opcache be forced to keep cached scripts in memory?

Tags: php, caching, memory, opcache

We run a production server with Apache and php-fpm with opcache enabled. Currently, opcache has been configured with an upper limit of 1024MB of usable memory.

However, when I recently profiled the server and opcache I noticed a sharp discrepancy between the actual memory used by FPM/opache, and the memory actually reported as used by the OS.

Profiling opcache, it tells me it is as of this moment using approximately 850MB of memory, caching some 8000 scripts. However, htop tells me that current processes are only using about 600MB of RAM, of which FPM takes up about 150MB.

I can only assume this means that opcache stores cached scripts on disk rather than RAM. However, as performance matters to us and we have RAM to spare, is there any way we can force opcache to store all its cached scripts in RAM instead?

Comment: Do you think that your scripts need more than 150MB or So ?

Comment: I would prefer if they were all kept in memory. We are running a dedicated shard with more than enough RAM to spare.

Comment: Opcache uses only ram to cache the script
Since opcache stores compiled opcode in memory, memory results will vary from profiler.

Just to add - You can check for other configuration like disabling filestamp check it wil reduce few ms.

Comment: I have already disabled timestamp checking and other dev-oriented settings, since this is a production server.

As I mentioned in the question, it is simply impossible that opcache are caching in memory here, unless either it or the OS are reporting false memory usage.

Comment: How you profiled opcache ?

Comment: https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status

Comment: Just a guess, that these numbers are different because of shared memory, It also differs how you calculate memory usage.  But for sure your scripts are cached in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Opcache already stores all compiled code (opcode) in memory.

> OPcache improves PHP performance by storing precompiled script
>   bytecode in shared memory, thereby removing the need for PHP to load
>   and parse scripts on each request.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

These numbers are varying because of differnce in way of calculating memory usage,  htop, top calculate using system API where as opcache_get_status uses internal methods in  computing same - http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_5/lcov_html/ext/opcache/zend_accelerator_module.c.gcov.php

This can be possible because of shared variables/memory optimization in language level.